# OpenBSD configs to EdgeRouter

Tags: routing, configuration, openbsd

is it possible to transfter OpenBSD router configs, such as firewall settings, DHCP settings to EdgeRouter-Lite?

Answer (score 0):

The EdgeRouter Lite is Linux-based (a Vyatta-derived distribution). I would strongly suspect that, given the relative dissimilarity of OpenBSD to Linux, there isn't any "turnkey" tool to do what you're looking for. Given how simple the EdgeRouter's configuration system is, though, it should be a fairly simple process to get the configuration manually translated.